# С++ работа с XML

Tags: c++, xml, поиск-библиотек

Подскажите популярные библиотеки С++ для работы с XML(для записи в него и считывание данных из него) или хороший источник с руководством для создания собственного парсера на основе DOM дерева.

Comment: первое, что приходит на ум [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) и куда менее менее популярные плюсовые [биндинги](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/) для оной.

Comment: есть ещё [expat](https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat). А свой без поддержки cdata пишется за день и длинной 500 строк.

Comment: Еще есть [tinyxml2](https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2), простая и легкая, парсит довольно быстро.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) - вполне работоспособная библиотека. Недавно сделал с её помощьщю чтение файлов конфигурации в формате XML c валидацией по схеме XSD.

Answer (score 0):

tinyxml - свободная, опенсорсная и реально клевая (простая и функциональная). Изначально работал с xml через 'qt' - там есть свой парсер, но tinyxml значительно удобнее.